# Why my program works slower after using a dll?

Tags: c++, dll, openmp

I am creating a dll in c++ where I will have some functions to use in a Delphi 7 project.

The first function I exported reduces drastically the performance of my program, I already checked with AQtime and the slowest function is the one from my dll.

The function simply checks if a given char is in the array, before using OpenMP directives it worked slowly as well, so it shouldn't be that.

```
bool Validate(char character)
{

char char_store[] = {',' , '+' , '-' , '*' , '/',
                     '(' , ')' , '^' , '[' , ']' ,
                     '%' , '&' , '=' , '<' , '>' ,
                     ' ' , '.' , ';' , ':', char(13) , char(10)};

bool abort = false;

#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
{
    #pragma omp flush (abort)
    if(!abort)
    {
        if (char_store[i] == character)
        {
            abort = true;
            #pragma omp flush (abort)
        }
    }
}
return abort;
}
```

I know in Delphi you can create a function to check the same thing in an easier way, but I find difficult to believe that this small array will cause my program to slow down from a matter of seconds to minutes.

I am using static loading for my dll.

function Validate(character: Char): Boolean; cdecl; external 'Library.dll';

Any reason why is this happening?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Delphi, as it asks nothing about Delphi. It's strictly a C++ question. Tags should have something to do with the question you're asking; the fact that you mention another language by name doesn't make that tag applicable.

Comment: I think it also has nothing to do with using a DLL (or maybe I just don't understand it?) ... seems like it's purely a question about OpenMP performance on a trivial task?

Answer (score 2):

Your function is trivial. It's a `for` loop with 21 iterations that performs a couple of simple equality tests. It can execute in ~100 cycles. The overhead of OpenMP is many orders of magnitude greater.

Simply put, you cannot expect threads to improve performance here. You need much larger tasks of work for threading to be effective. Single threaded code written in Delphi will be the most efficient way to implement the code in your question.

If removing all the OpenMP doesn't help (you say your code is slow without the OpenMP) then you need to look at your compiler options. Are you compiling with optimisation? If you have a question about performance, you do really need to supply a reproducible test case, with timings.

Your C++ code is rather strange too. It is needlessly complex. It could be written like this:

```
bool Validate(const char character)
{    
    const char char_store[] = {
        ',' , '+' , '-' , '*' , '/', '(' , ')' , '^' , '[' , ']' , '%' ,
        '&' , '=' , '<' , '>' , ' ' , '.' , ';' , ':',
        char(13) , char(10)};

    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)        
        if (char_store[i] == character)            
            return true;                    
    return false;
}
```

There's no point whatsoever in putting this code in a DLL, or trying to use a parallel `for`. You need to break your program into much bigger units of work for parallelisation to be effective.

Comment: The C++ code is not strange when seen in the context of OpenMP. OpenMP in versions before 4.0 does not support cancellation, i.e. one cannot terminate prematurely a worksharing construct when some criterion is reached and one cannot simply `return` from inside a parallel construct too, therefore one has to write such code. This usually works but only if the loop body is very complex and each iteration takes a lot of time. In any case, it's a misuse of OpenMP.